# Probabilities are ignored in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to use the numpy library to sample a character from a distribution, but it seems to ignore the probabilities I give in input.
I have a probability array, which just to test I set to

```
vec_p=[0,0,1,0,0]
```

and a character array

```
vec_c=[a,b,c,d,e]
```

If I do

```
numpy.random.choice(vec_c,10,vec_p)
```

I would expect to get

```
cccccccccc
```

since the other probabilities are all zero, but it just gives me random values ignoring the vec_p array. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use `p=vec_p` .

Comment: Divakar's comment and Moses' answer are good. The thing is, that you provided 3 parameters with p beeing the third. Numpy expects it to be the 4th one. So using keywords is a nice way. Of course you should be able to just give the 3rd parameter also, e.g. ```numpy.random.choice(vec_c,10,True,vec_p)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the parameters as keyword arguments gives the correct results:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> vec_p = [0,0,1,0,0]
>>> num = np.arange(5)
>>> np.random.choice(num, size=10, p=vec_p)
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```